# Is there an algorithm for identifying numbers in a set which are different by one digit?

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic

In a set of six digit numbers of size n, is there an algorithm which can identify numbers in that set which are different by one digit without comparing each element to every other element directly? Is it possible to do this in less than O(n!)?

For example, in the following set of numbers:

789000
889000
543200
125894
156795
146795

789000 and 889000 are different by one digit. 156795 and 146795 are also different by one digit. These numbers would need to be identified by the algorithm.

Comment: Why would this be O(n!)?

Comment: I was thinking that you would need to compare each number to every subsequent number. It didn't occur to me to frame it in the way you did.

Comment: A solution comparing all pairs of numbers would be O(n^2), not n factorial - n factorial would occur if you were iterating over all permutations of the whole sequence.

Comment: Absolutely! I didn’t think that was necessary in this case. For example, in the set 55 67 52 54 once you have compared 55 the next 3 elements there is no need to compare 67 to 55 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward solution is asymptotically optimal:

```py
def elements_one_apart(the_set):
    result = set() # create a new set

    for x in the_set:
        for y in numbers_different_from_x_by_one_digit(x):
            if y in the_set:
                result.add(x)
                break # skip to the next value of x

    return result
```

The outer loop iterates over n elements of `the_set`, and the inner loop iterates over at most 6 * 9 = 54 values of `y`. So the number of iterations of the inner loop is O(n).

The `in` and `add` operations each take O(1) time, if you use a [hash-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Sets). So the overall time complexity is O(n). If the input is not a hash-set, then it can be converted into a hash-set in O(n) time, so the algorithm is still O(n)

No solution can possibly be faster than O(n) time, because any lower complexity is insufficient to look at all of the numbers in `the_set`.

Comment: Thanks! The pedant in me is insisting I note that the inner loop will need to iterate over 59 values for y, as 0 is a possibility in all but the leftmost digit.

Comment: @MasterArcanist the correct number is 53 for the reason about 0 - not 59, because there are only 9 (not 10) choices for what to replace each of 6 digits with. The 10th choice would leave the number `x` the same.